# transferring hard coded data to arrays

Tags: c#, mysql, arrays, winforms

Okay so I would like to ask for people's advice on how to improve my code, there are no problems with it, I feel weird coming onto this site not having problems with code.

Currently, my code is lacking complexity, it is hard code by definition, I want to know if there are ways that I can reduce hard code by transferring the data into arrays or loops.

I have some of my code here I think a small snippet shall suffice.

```
 MySqlDataAdapter dAdapter = new MySqlDataAdapter(pQuery, Connection);
            dAdapter.Fill(dTable);
            dAdapter.Dispose();
            int One, Two, Three;
            One = Convert.ToInt32(dTable.Rows[0]["Cost"].ToString());
            Two = Convert.ToInt32(dTable.Rows[1]["Cost"].ToString());
            Three = Convert.ToInt32(dTable.Rows[2]["Cost"].ToString());
```

Of course ignore the pQuery and Connection. I feel like I'm taking the 'long way around' whereas I'm sure there is a cleaner way of doing this.

Any suggestions?

Comment: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ for what you're asking, but why not making a class for the data, I mean, you're getting the cost of something right, make a class for that something with its cost space.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, you could use a list and a loop like this:

```
var costs = new List<int>();
foreach (DataRow row in dTable.Rows) {
    costs.Add(Convert.ToInt32(row["Cost"].ToString());
}
```

Also note that you can use a `using` block instead of explicitly calling `Dispose`:

```
using (var dAdapter = new MySqlDataAdapter(pQuery, Connection)) {
    dAdapter.Fill(dTable);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Similarly, you could do it in one line with LINQ. Not that one line is better, just another way:

```
List<int> costs = (dTable.Rows
    .Cast<DataRow>()
    .Select(row => int.Parse(row["Cost"].ToString())))
    .ToList();
```